# SPEAK Combobox options binding

Tags: speak

I am currently implementing a module on SPEAK UI. I have a dialog which shows up when the user clicks on a button. Then, on the dialog, I have a `label` with a `combo box` which displays a list of items.

The list is retrieved as follows:

```
define(["sitecore", "jquery"], function (sitecore, $) {

    var initStepDefinition = sitecore.Definitions.App.extend({

        initialized: function () {
            this.getOptions();
        },
        getOptions: function () {
            var app = this;

            $.get("/api/experimental/getoptionlist").done(
                function (data) {
                    app.OptionBox.set("items",data);
                }
            );          
        }
    });

    return initStepDefinition;
});
```

Now, I need to display a form under the `combo box` when the user selects an item from the list. The `data` being returned from the server is a list of objects (Value and Text) and converted into `JSON`.

**Question:** I don't know how to bind in the `change event` so that on each selection, I get the Id of the selected item.

**Note**

I've seen that Sitecore makes use of the `Knockout.js` and that it is the `options: items` data bind which I need to check but I don't know how. I am new to the SPEAK Framework and this is the first module I am implementing using SPEAK.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have been able to do it by using the event `change:selectedItemId`. Below is the code that I have used:

```
define(["sitecore", "jquery"], function (sitecore, $) {

    var initStepDefinition = sitecore.Definitions.App.extend({

        initialized: function () {
            this.getOptions();
            this.getChangeOption();
        },
        getOptions: function () {
            var app = this;

            $.get("/api/experimental/getoptionlist").done(
                function (data) {
                    app.OptionBox.set("items",data);
                }
            );          
        },
        getChangeOption: function (){
            var app = this;

            app.OptionBox.on("change:selectedItemId", (function (){
                alert(app.OptionBox.viewModel.selectedItemId());
            }));
        }
    });

    return initStepDefinition;
});
```